# Understanding MEANJS.org HTML template rendering

Tags: html, client-side, server-side-rendering

Is MEANJS.org rendering HTML server side or via the client?

Its view engine

```
/**
 * Configure view engine
 */
module.exports.initViewEngine = function (app) {
  app.engine('server.view.html', hbs.express4({
    extname: '.server.view.html'
  }));
  app.set('view engine', 'server.view.html');
  app.set('views', path.resolve('./'));
};
```

From what I understand about Express, is you set a `view engine` for server side template rendering.

And a little further down in the same file it has

```
/**
 * Configure the modules static routes
 */
module.exports.initModulesClientRoutes = function (app) {
  // Setting the app router and static folder
  app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve('./public'), { maxAge: 86400000 }));

  // Globbing static routing
  config.folders.client.forEach(function (staticPath) {
    app.use(staticPath, express.static(path.resolve('./' + staticPath)));
  });
};
```

Which is used for client side assets, from what I understand.

There is also this, which from the comment alone, leads to me believe that its all server side rendering - `res.render()` - is server side, right?

```
/**
 * Render the main application page
 */
exports.renderIndex = function (req, res) {
  var safeUserObject = null;
  if (req.user) {
    safeUserObject = {
      displayName: validator.escape(req.user.displayName),
      provider: validator.escape(req.user.provider),
      username: validator.escape(req.user.username),
      created: req.user.created.toString(),
      roles: req.user.roles,
      profileImageURL: req.user.profileImageURL,
      email: validator.escape(req.user.email),
      lastName: validator.escape(req.user.lastName),
      firstName: validator.escape(req.user.firstName),
      additionalProvidersData: req.user.additionalProvidersData
    };
  }

  res.render('modules/core/server/views/index', {
    user: JSON.stringify(safeUserObject),
    sharedConfig: JSON.stringify(config.shared)
  });
};
```

I'm just trying to understand what is going on here... is it server-side or client-side or a combination of both?

**UPDATE 1 (3/2/17)**
I think I now realize a bit more of what is going on. It seems that MEANJS.org uses server side authentication (sessions etc) to provide the authentication for user accounts. It has not been updated yet to use token based authentication... or from what I understand, aka, client side auth... which seems to be gaining in popularity these days.